# How do I import a Model from another Model in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model

Desc Model belongsTo Prod Model. I want that all Prod.Name will appear as checkboxes when adding a new desc, so that user will just click a Prod.Name when adding a new description for it. Like:

```
<?php
echo $form->create('Desc');
echo $form->checkBox(Prod.Name); // assuming this is the correct code.
echo $form->textArea('Desc.content');
echo $form->end('Save');
?>
```

I'm still not familiar with this framework, still messing with it.

Thanks!

So far this is what I did:

```
<select name='data[Desc][prod_id]' id='DescriptionProdId'>
<?php echo $form->create('Desc'); ?>
<?php foreach($opps as $opp): ?>
<option value="<?php $opp["Prod"]["id"] ?>">
<?php echo $opp["Prod"]["name"]; ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: What you are trying to do and what you are doing are two different things.
If your desc belongs to prod make sure you define that in your models with var $belongsTo and var $hasOne, you should read the doc on associations.
var $uses should not be used in this situation at all

Comment: Yeah, I already did that. Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating the  element manually, you should use the FormHelper.

In your view:

```
<?php
echo $form->input('prod_id', array('options' => $opps));
?>
```

Cakephp will make the select input, using the $opps records as the options.  You can also set other options other than the 'options' option.  Check out:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements

If you specify the view variable as prods in your controller action, then you do not need to specify the options key of the $options array.  In the controller action:

```
$this->set('prods', $this->find('all'));
```

Comment: will it display all the prod name in the database?

Comment: Yes.  You should never write custom form elements with cakephp.  Learn how to use the FormHelper.

Comment: In your $form->checkbox() call, the argument is missing the string quotations around it.  Also, you should always use $form->input(), and cakephp will output the appropriate form type based on the database schema.  If you need a different input type, then use this option: $form->input('Model.field', array('type' => 'textarea'));

Comment: `$this->set('prods', $this->Desc->Prod->find('list'));` .. if you name your variable plural like this (`$prods`), cakephp will automatically populate the select box, so you don't have to provide the `'options' => $opps` part.